# Trigger async tasks from other activity?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity

how can I trigger AsyncTasks that are contained in another activity from my main activity?

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    private class DbReader extends AsyncTask<..> {
        @Override
        protected List<MyData> doInBackground(..) {
            //execute query etc
        }
    }

    private class DbSaver extends AsyncTask<..> {
        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(MyData data) {
            //save to dn
        }
    }

    private class DbRemover extends AsyncTask<..> {
        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(MyData data) {
            //remove in db
        }
    }
}
```

How can I trigger from MyApplication extends Actitivy?

Comment: Do you really need this AsycTasks to be inside this activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should `use seperate class where AsyncTask is alone.`

when your app needs more than one AsyncTask then you should use seperate AsyncTask and call it.

```
private class CommonTask extends AsyncTask<..> {
   public CommonTask(Foo foo){

       } 

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(MyData data) {
            //remove in db
        }
    }
```

No you can pass diffrent value for constructor and check what you want from Activity either data save or remove or anything else...

Comment: You mean different doInBackground methods taking different parameters, and then calling just myTask.execute(params)? If so, I think in code will be very confisung if you get different action by passing differen params. eg passing a string > save; passing my object > remove; passing id > fetch.

Comment: @membersound if you confused then create seperate each class like `savetask`,`removetask` ...this is last solution for you